# Convert Action<T, T, T> to Task<T, T, T>?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have a list of `Action`, and I want to utilize `async/await`, but I don't know how to convert the following code (simplified example) to use af list of `Task` instead? Importantly, I need to somehow get the name of the action inside each task and also to make sure, the tasks completes before continuing to the next, inside the `ForEach` loop. My code runs in `Main` in `Program`.

Note: The actions are being invoked with 3 parameters, so I need the tasks to be also "invoked" similarly with the same parameters.

```
new List<Action<string, string, string>>()
{
   Action1,
   Action2,
   Action3,
   Action4,
   Action5
   // etc...
}.ForEach(action => {
   Console.WriteLine("Invoking action: " + action.Method.Name + " ...");
   action.Invoke("Hello", "World", "!");
   // do other stuff...
});
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It sounds like you want to convert your actions into `Func<T,T,T,Task>`

Comment: Rather than `Action<string, string, string>` you would need `Func<string, string, string, Task>`, meaning the delegate returns an awaitable `Task`. Also note that this wouldn't play nice with `List<T>.ForEach`, because you can't await that method, meaning you wouldn't know when all the delegates have completed. You can either use `Task.WhenAll` or a standard `foreach` depending on your requirements.

Comment: "Utilize" `async`/`await` how exactly? If your methods aren't doing anything `async` and you want to execute them sequentially, there's not much happening in the way of asynchrony.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay, @Jonesopolis - Can U give examples?
@JeroenMostert  - My methods are calling other async methods, hence I want to convert them to `Task` to utilize `async/await` in my main program

Comment: Could you include in the question an example of an action? For example the `Action1`. We just need to see the signature of the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a version that runs the work sequentially:

```
public static async Task Main()
{
    // Action<string,string,string> becomes
    // Func<string,string,string, Task> because the worker methods 
    // return a Task, not void
    var work = new List<Func<string, string, string, Task>>()
    {
        X,
        X2,
    };
        
    foreach(var t in work)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invoking action: " + t.Method.Name + " ...");
        await t("Hello", "World", "!").ConfigureAwait(false);
    };
}
```

---

#### Test

With

```
static async Task X(string a, string b, string c)
{
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1)).ConfigureAwait(false);
    Console.WriteLine($"{a} {b} {c}");
}

static async Task X2(string a, string b, string c)
{
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1)).ConfigureAwait(false);
    Console.WriteLine($"{c} {b} {a}");
}
```

this prints

```
Invoking action: X ...
Hello World !
Invoking action: X2 ...
! World Hello
```

Answer (score 0):

A basic example of what you are trying to do would be along the lines of:

```
var actions = new List<Action<string, string, string>>();
            
//....

var funcs = actions.Select(x => new Func<string, string, string, Task>((one, two, three) =>
{
    x(one, two, three);
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}));


var tasks = new List<Task>();
foreach(var func in funcs)
{
    tasks.Add(func("one", "two", "three")); //wherever these parameters come from
}

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Comment: The OP hasn't said that they want to launch all the asynchronous operations concurrently.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias you're not wrong.  But they did ask for sample code and I took a guess at what they wanted due to lack of information so I could provide a more robust example

Comment: Thank you @Jonesopolis - your answer came closest to my own solution:

`
Task.WhenAll(new Func<SPClientContext, string, DateTime, Task>[]
                {
                    Action1,
                    Action2,
                    Action3
                }.Select(async func =>
                {
                     Console.WriteLine("Invoking action: " + func.Method.Name + " ...");
                     await func.Invoke("Hello", "World", "!");
                })).ContinueWith(_ =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("All done!");
                });
`